# Sonar warning S6857: Correct this malformed property placeholder - is this a false positive?

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarlint, sonarcloud

I have a very simple spring boot configuration class like this:

```java
@Getter
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {
    @Value("${some.property:some default if property is unset}")
    private String someProperty;
}
```

This **works**. If some.property is set, someProperty is set to this value - otherwise it's set to the default.

But recently both SonarLint and SonarCloud have started [complaining](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/spring/RSPEC-6857/):

> Correct this malformed property placeholder.
>
> SpEL expression should have a valid syntax java:S6857

(removing the spaces removes the warning - but removing them would be wrong)

Before I close this as a false positive, I'd like to know if my analysis is correct: According to the [@Value javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html), the value passed to @Value is *either* a SpEL expression *or* a property injected via `${}`. But validating the latter with rules for the former is doomed to fail. Is this correct?

Comment: Have you tried putting the default value between quotes (either single `'` or escaped double `\"`) to see if that satisfies the rule? Those code checkers are generally pretty dumb as they lack context.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, I tried that - no change.

Comment: Well as stated, those checks are dumb. A false positive at the best. Not sure how that rule is implemented in Sonar but maybe it might be something to update or provide a ticket for.